# Generics collection and method returning type

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface with a method

```
public List< Object > getLeftBusinessObjects( List< Object > businessObjectIds, Object owningSystemId );
```

My implementation is:

```
public List<Object> getLeftBusinessObjects(List< Object > businessObjectIds, Object owningSystemId)
{    
    List<MyObject> myObjs= Helper.getMyObjects(businessObjectIds);
    return myObjs;
}
```

Doing so I get the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<MyObject> to List<Object>
```

I have to double cast this way

```
return (List<Object>) (Object) myObjs;
```

to avoid the error.

Can someone explain me why? Why do I have to cast if all objects have per dafault Object as superclass?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `List<MyObject>` is not a `List<Object>.`,because otherwise you would be able to put an `Object` into a `List<MyObject>`

try this

```
public List<? extends Object> getLeftBusinessObjects(List< Object > businessObjectIds, Object owningSystemId)
{    
    List<MyObject> myObjs= Helper.getMyObjects(businessObjectIds);
    return myObjs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the list that `getLeftBusinessObjects()` returns by adding any object of type `Object` to it. This breaks type safety, because the list returned by `Helper.getMyObjects(businessObjectIds)` is guaranteed to only hold objects of type `MyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) nor covariance in generics in java.

thus: `List<MyObject>` does not extend `List<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

Generics are used for compile time validation of objects, we add into collections. So, you expecting `MyObject` as your objects in list `List<MyObject> myObjs`, that means you want to add only those objects. But your are assigning `List<Object>` to `List<MyObject> myObjs`, means that List can have any class object, so it breaks the contract of generics. So, compiler gives the developer to decide whether it's safe to assign `List<Object>` to `List<MyObject> myObjs`, as there are chances of `ClassCastException` at run-time.